# Inserir Botão Whatsapp Share em páginas HTML

Tags: html

Como inserir um Botão compartilhar no Whatsapp em projetos HTML?

Comment: Bem vinda ao [pt.so]. Poderia explicar melhor a sua dúvida? O que esse comando deve fazer? O que você já tem feito até agora? Aproveite e confira o guia [ask].

Comment: Usa esse site. Ele gera para você. http://whatsapp-sharing.com/

Comment: @Gisele, se sera um APP, você o esta desenvolvido 100% em HTML? Utiliza Phonegap? Qual framework esta utilizando? Coloque as  tecnologias e linguagens (framework) que utiliza e alguns códigos que você ja tenha no projeto e poderemos ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode utilizar o esquema de URL `whatsapp://send?text=` no atributo **`href`** de um *hyperlink* seguido da mensagem que será compartilhada. Por exemplo:

```html
<a href='whatsapp://send?text=StackOverflow'>compartilhar</a>
```

Se o usuário tiver o aplicativo instalado, ele será inicializado permitindo que seja escolhido um contato junto a um campo de texto que permite editar a mensagem antes do envio.

Como ainda não é possível acessar o Whatsapp pelo navegador da mesma forma como é feita em dispositivos móveis — no *desktop* esse esquema de URL é desconhecido — talvez seja interessante esconder esse *link* e exibi-lo somente em telas menores:

```css
/**
 * Tamanho somente para ilustrar! Tenha em mente que
 * a instalação do aplicativo não é restrita a smartphones.
 */
@media screen and (min-width: 860px){
  .compartilhar-whatsapp {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Alguns links nas perguntas frequentes do aplicativo que cita o uso desse esquema de url customizado:

- [FAQ Iphone](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/pt_br/iphone/23559013)
- [FAQ Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

Comment: Oi, este tipo de link que abre um aplicativo externo tem algum nome específico? Onde posso encontrar mais informações sobre?

Comment: Se chama `Custom URI scheme`