# Enviar mensagem Whatsapp pelo link no site

Tags: android, html, iphone, whatsapp

Gostaria de saber como enviar uma mensagem por um link para um determinado número. Já consegui fazer para `Android`, mas para `iPhone` não funciona.

Link:

```
<a href="intent://send/123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">
```

Comment: Pode colocar o que você já tentou fazer para o iPhone?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar na verdade não sei como fazer para iPhone. Gostaria de algo que funcione nos dois.

Comment: Fala Moises, Eu não programo pra Iphone então não vou saber te explicar, mas no próprio site do WhatsAPP tem a explicação do que você deve fazer, segue o link: [https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/pt_br/iphone/23559013](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/pt_br/iphone/23559013) Abraços.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Inserir Botão Whatsapp Share em páginas HTML](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70475/inserir-bot%c3%a3o-whatsapp-share-em-p%c3%a1ginas-html)

Answer (score 1):

Para uso no iPhone, use este formato:

`whatsapp://send?text=Texto da mensagem com link http://google.com`

Answer (score 1):

É possível também criar um link usando a API do WhatsApp e determinar qual o número de destino. Funciona também com os aplicativos desktop:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5511999999999">Enviar mensagem</a>
```

Importante: é preciso inserir o código do país (55) e o DDD.