# É possível adicionar um contato no celular via código?

Tags: html, mobile, link

Em uma lista de usuários num sistema mobile é possível ter um botão que adicione o contato no celular ?

Seria um botão **ADD** que, quando clicasse, aparecesse aquela tela de adicionar contato do Android, por exemplo, com o nome da pessoa e o número já preenchido nos campos.

Encontrei a TAG:

`<a href="tel: 19 99999999"> 19 999999 </a>`

Assim a pessoa escolhe o que fazer, ligar, mandar SMS ou adicionar nos contatos.

Parecida com o `mailto:`.

Mas especificamente para o que eu quero não achei ainda.

Comment: Provavelmente não, é algo que precisa ser criado [igual o Whatsapp fez](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70508/4808).

Comment: Na verdade o `mailto:` não adiciona a lugar nenhum, o que ele faz é semelhante ao `tel:` ele chama o aplicativo de comunicação, no `tel:` faz uma chamada e no `mailto:` chama o compor e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar uma coisa que está dentro do celular pelo navegador. Observe, é a mesma coisa que tentar acessar um recurso do teu pc pelo chrome, por exemplo, sem um "carinha" lá pra te repassar essa informação não vejo muitas opções. Mais vc pode dar uma pesquisada pra ver se alguma browser fornece esse "carinha" que faça a cola entre o js e o celular.

Abaixo um exemplo de como seria usando java:

```java
 String DisplayName = "XYZ";
 String MobileNumber = "123456";
 String HomeNumber = "1111";
 String WorkNumber = "2222";
 String emailID = "email@nomail.com";
 String company = "bad";
 String jobTitle = "abcd";

 ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
 ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
     .build());

 //------------------------------------------------------ Names
 if (DisplayName != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
     ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
     DisplayName).build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number                     
 if (MobileNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
     newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
 if (HomeNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
 if (WorkNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Email
 if (emailID != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Organization
 if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact                 
 try {
     getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     Toast.makeText(myContext, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: Beleza. E onde eu implemento isso (que eu nem sei, nem imagino o que seja) no meu HTML ?

Comment: Vejo que vc é iniciante com android certo? Aqui tem um tutorial de como listar contatos: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/. Vc vai precisar criar um projeto novo, criar uma interface (similar ao html) e depois juntar as duas coisas.

Comment: Não, eu não sou iniciante em Android. Eu nunca comecei. Meu sistema é em HTML5. Só quero saber se existe um comando, uma tag que me permita clicar e adicionar o contato. A mais perto que achei foi a `tel:`.

Comment: Vc conhece algo sobre rest?

Comment: Eu não sei o que é Rest. Pode me abrir a mente, por favor ?

Comment: Vamos lá, vc está acessando uma página HTML pelo celular certo? Nesse caso vai precisar chegar dentro do celular aonde roda java certo? Nesse caso vc pode criar uma aplicação rest e rodar um javascript pelo browser do celular para então acessar a camada java (aonde estão os contatos). Aqui tem um exemplo de aplicação rest: http://www.k19.com.br/artigos/criando-um-webservice-restful-em-java/

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado. Eu entendi a sequência lógica. Apenas assim que é possível fazer ?

Comment: Bem, a questão como falei é que vc está tentando acessar uma coisa que está dentro do celular pelo navegador. Observe, é a mesma coisa que tentar acessar um recurso do teu pc pelo chrome, por exemplo, sem um "carinha" lá pra te repassar essa informação não vejo muitas opções. Mais vc pode dar uma pesquisada pra ver se alguma browser fornece esse "carinha" que faça a cola entre o js e o celular

Comment: A pergunta esta usando tag html e link, portanto a resposta deveria apresentar algo proximo a isto e se não for possivel, deveria estar descrito aonde este seu código deveria ir e que tecnologia ele usa, por exemplo: "Com html não é possivel, mas se for Android, você pode usar o java etc etc". Recomendo que melhore a resposta amigo

Comment: A resposta foi alterada e mesmo assim fui negativado. Querem que melhore ainda mais? Preciso ser mais especifico?

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, infelizmente terá que esperar os usuários que negativaram passarem aqui, talvez eles não tenham visto a edição, vou lhe dar um voto positivo, mas uma duvida, o que é "carinha"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o "carinha" foi uma forma genérica de chamar o serviço no lado do celular que irá expor uma interface para o lado cliente consumir as informações. Entendo que usar termos genérico pode não ser o ideal. Entretanto, colocar respostas complexas para um usuário que não conhece muito sobre tal tecnologia pode desencorajar o mesmo a prosseguir com o desenvolvimento devido a sua complexidade. Nesse tópico certamente iria ajuda-lo explicando o que seria esse "carinha", mais antes, ele precisa entender o o básico do funcionamento mobile

Comment: Ainda acho melhor usar por nomes que possam ser pesquisáveis depois independente do AP conhecer ou não as tecnologias. No caso é um protocolo que chama uma aplicação, semelhante a um `Intent`, então o termo talvez seja aplicação ou ao invés de dizer *"ver se alguma browser fornece esse carinha"* seria legal dizer *"ver se alguma browser fornece suporte pra este protocolo"*

Comment: A questão não seria bem um protocolo e sim uma interface de comunicação que prove dados internos do SO. Mais enfim, no final das contas todos tem a mesma idéia, ajudar e ser ajudado. Abraços e boa semana